# use and access style variable in react native

Tags: react-native

I just started with react-native and i'm fiddling with the styles. I want to use something i always do when working with Sass and that's creating a global configuration file with variables i can use throughout the Sass files. In Sass i would do the following:

style.scss

```
@import 'config/_config';
@import 'base/_base';
```

Then in _config.scss i would put something like `$fontColor: 'red';` and then in _base.scss something like this:

```
p{
  color: $fontColor
}
```

When i compile the sass files to a single css i get the expected

```
p{
  color: 'red';
}
```

Now i'm trying the same in react-native, but i can't get it to work. The closest i get with a 'result' (meaning: no error, but no result either) is this:

My file **App.js** contains the following

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>My first app</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = require('./style/Style.js');
```

**style/Style.js** looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import s from './config/Variables.js';

module.exports = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: s.backColor,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

and **style/config/Variables.js** like

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const backColor = '#4F5B66';
```

I've also tried `const styles = { backColor: '#4F5B66'};`, but that didn't work either.

How can i make this work?

Comment: I solved it by defining the variables in Variables.js without `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by defining the variables without `const` so Variables.js becomes

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

backColor = '#4F5B66';
```